# Document sets shown in Calendar view instead of individual documents

Tags: 2013, calendar, document-set

We have a document library in SP2013 that uses document sets to store meeting minutes, agendae, etc.

When we create a calendar view however, it shows the individual documents instead of the document sets.

Changing the view to filter on "content type" = "meeting" doesn't change anything.

Any idea how to get the calendar view to only display the document set, and not show files inside the doc set?

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround but was happy to figure it out so thought I'd share.

I have another field in my document set's content type called Retention ID. For all of my document sets, I enter 0001 as the value for Retention ID. I set my calendar view to filter on Retention ID = 0001 then I get one entry that is linked to the document set.